# Update MySQL: Duplicate unique key #1062

Tags: mysql, key, duplicates, unique

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activity` (
  `ID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `categoryID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`userID`,`categoryID`),
  KEY `categoryID` (`categoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

With the next information:

```
INSERT INTO `activity` (`ID`, `action`, `userID`, `categoryID`) VALUES
(1, 2, 11, 312);
```

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
UPDATE `activity` SET `action` = '3' WHERE `userID` = '11' AND `categoryID` = '312' ;
```

And response me with that:

```
Duplicate entry '11-312' for key 'UNIQUE'
```

I don't know why. I ain't changing unique keys or inserting another new record. What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce, but the update works for me. What client are you using?

Comment: Do you have a trigger on your table?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, when I export whole database, instead of show before SQL, show this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `activity` (
  `ID` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `action` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `userID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `categoryID` int(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`action`,`userID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Now I rewrite setup table sql and it works.